# Html позиционирование фона

Tags: html, css

Это глюк или у меня кривые руки?
Есть блок `<div id='main'>`

```
#main{
min-height: 450px;  
display: block;  
border: 0px solid #6F3833;  
background-image: url('/css/images/portret.jpg');  
background-repeat: no-repeat;  
background-position: right center;  
background-attachment: scroll;  
padding-right: 350px;
text-align: center;    
}
```

Если толщина границы не нуль, картинка фона по вертикали выравнивается по центру, а если нет границы - съезжает вниз. Это как так?

---

Взял и добавил белую границу, с глюком справиться не удалось.

Comment: Я тут ради такого дела даже запустил IE(7)... Нету глюка. При включении границы - тоже. Ссылку бы... И браузер в котором проявляется.

Comment: не пропустил #(  #main{ .....)?

Comment: @Dazar, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Попробуй поиграться с `background-origin`, может, это что-то изменит.

Я вот для себя уяснил, что это свойство вообще лучше указывать насильно, ибо некоторые браузеры только-только научились его поддерживать, что у меня лично вызвало некоторые недопонимания, особенно - в случае с Оперой.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
#main{
   min-height: 450px;  
   display: block;  
   border: 0 solid #6F3833;  
   background: url('/css/images/portret.jpg') no-repeat center center;
                                                /*либо - right center*/  
   background-attachment: scroll;  
   padding-right: 350px;
   text-align: center;    
}
```

Должно помочь...

Answer (score 0):

Всё получается. См.пример:

```css
#main{
  min-height: 450px;  
  display: block;  
  border: 1px solid #6F3833;  
  background-image: url('https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/icocentre-free-icons/170/f-command_256-512.png');  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;  
  background-position: center center;  
  background-attachment: scroll;  
  text-align: center;    
}
```

```html
<div id='main'>
```

Comment: зачем вы отвечаете на вопросы шестилетней давности?

Comment: Хороший вопрос)))) а я дату как-то и не заметил, хаха)